# JQuery - click on href ID not being recognized on one page, works on all the others

Tags: jquery

Probably best you look at this in Chrome.

http://onrepeatthisweek.tumblr.com/post/39128891344/011-milhaven-supervulkan

If you click the comments link at the bottom of the page you'll see the desired behaviour (minus a bit of styling).

If you click on any of the other songs along the bottom you'll see that the comments link has the same desired behaviour...

APART FROM the first song: 
http://onrepeatthisweek.tumblr.com/post/39129026301/012-keane-clear-skies-villa-remix

Where the click isn't being recognised.

The function:

```
function showAndPlayTune() {
document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'inline';

//then autoplay it plus change the UI to pause
document.getElementById('GristyPlayer').play();
document.getElementById('GristyPlayer-Play').click();

//and display the player page favicon
var faviconPlayLink = document.createElement('link');
faviconPlayLink.type = 'image/x-icon';
faviconPlayLink.rel = 'shortcut icon';
faviconPlayLink.href = 'http://www.thomasgrist.co.uk/totw/img/favicon2-play.png';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(faviconPlayLink);

//and apply a highlight to the page / song that we're on, plus setup the comments link
$('a[href$="' + currenturl2 + '"]').css("font-family", "\'Apercu Bold\'");
$('a[href$="' + currenturl2 + '"]').parent().css("background-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
$('a[href$="' + currenturl2 + '"]').append('<br/><span style="text-decoration:underline;font-family:\'Apercu Regular\';">Comments</span>');
$('a[href$="' + currenturl2 + '"]').attr({
href: "#",
id: "openComments"
});

//fade in social overlay on Facebook click
$("#openComments").click(function() {
    alert('click');
$("#commentsOverlay").fadeIn(400);
});

}

//run that function
window.onload = showAndPlayTune;
```

Comment: This is totally working correctly for me...

Comment: So if you go here: http://onrepeatthisweek.tumblr.com/post/39129026301/012-keane-clear-skies-villa-remix and click comments in the bottom left, you get the click alert and then a red background?